# Google Chrome does not show errors in console

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using Chrome for debugging and probably it was updated or something happened to it but now I cannot see the error messages my application has.

It only shows how many errors there are, like this:

[image]

I guess that some setting must be changed but don't know where and how.

How can it be changed to get the error messages?

Comment: Remove `bb-ygrid-lines` from the filter input box. Also make sure you didn't check "hide network errors" in devtools settings.

Comment: I removed `bb-ygrid-lines` but I don't find devtools settings. I clicked on the 3 vertical dots icon and from the opened menu I've selected Settings but there is nothing like "hide network errors" there.

Comment: Sounds like your Chrome is totally broken then.

Comment: I had the same issue, I had checked "hide network" checkbox. Unchecking it resolved the issue. @wOxxOm

Comment: It's called Hide Network Messages as of 2023, and it's under the main inspector bar's 'gear' icon > Preferences (sidebar) > under the sub-category "Console".

Answer (score 115, accepted):

I didn't find the reason of this issue but it was solved when I clicked on **Restore defaults and reload** button from Settings.

[image: Select Cog icon]

[image: Bottom right, select restore]

Comment: Have same issue after updating chrome and restore defaults didn't help.

Comment: In my case, restore defaults didn't help.

Comment: This helped for me, but man, what a weird issue.

Comment: The reason that this solved it for me is because restoring results cleared the search filter. You can see in the original question the user has 'bb-ygrid-lines' in the search filter so it will only show results that pass that filter. (So restoring defaults does work but just getting rid of the search is more straight forward)

Comment: Not sure what I'd done also but this worked for me

Answer (score 41):

The issue may be because you have checked some filter in console.

Try to uncheck it.

It works for me by uncheck "Selected Context only"
[image]

Comment: I did have "Group similar" checked, but that seems to be the default setting and removing it did not change anything. The other answer to use the "Restore defaults and reload" button did work however.

Comment: Just a comment to this one. You might also have something typed in the Filter filed. This in most cases will make all console messages disappear till you clear that field back.

Comment: The screenshot was misleading for me. I had to uncheck 'Selected context only' and check 'Preserve log' to see errors.

Answer (score 25):

Try to delete everything from filters:

[image]

Comment: thanks. I have tried all the checkbox, but my problem is really because something is still in filter with the same font color like "Filter" and just ignored sometimes.

Answer (score 9):

Check the console search bar. You had something typed in it, so if it doesn't find that search request then it won't show anything. I just ran into the same problem. Chrome should add a statement mentioning that some console results are hidden or some kind of warning.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Uncheck two options.
Hide Network and Select Context only

Comment: 'Selected Context only' unchecked worked for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screenshot when I solved the issue]

Keeping the following option checked and unchecked worked for me. In case you have an issue, here is the picture. Mostly, using selected context only, hiding network messages, enable custom formatters did the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

I unchecked Selected context only , fixed the issue
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I solved a similar problem by selecting the all levels dropdown and setting it to default:

[image: console filter options]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Inspect >> console >> Log level: select(Default levels)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This page was useful for testing https://devtools.glitch.me/console/log.html

This test page works but the page I was dev'ing on localhost was behaving as per OPs situation; logs counted in the sidebar but no output.

Sanity checking in Safari also showed no logged output.

So I added a `console.log` in some JS early on in my page and that logged fine.

Conclusion, I think I am misunderstanding how the Chrome console sidebar works. It's not actually hiding my page's logs but some other logs that I assumed were from my code. I don't know why.

Answer (score -1):

in my case, I was using console.group, console.groupcollapsed
I did not close the group using console.end().